# Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: typescript, templates

typescript report error in `{item}` "Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'." Not sure how to fix this error.

```
"@types/node": "^16.11.47",
"@types/react": "^18.0.17",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.7.4",
```

```
type ListProps<T> = {
  items: T[];
  onClick: (value: T) => void;
};

export const List = <T extends {}>({ items, onClick }: ListProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List of items</h2>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
            {item}  //ERROR
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, propsts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure out. Put restriction

```
type ListProps<T> = {
  items: T[];
  onClick: (value: T) => void;
};

export const List = <T extends string | number>({
  items,
  onClick,
}: ListProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>List of items</h2>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index} onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type ListProps<T> = {
 items: T[];
 onClick: (value: T) => void;
  };

  const List = <T extends { id: number; fname: string; lname: string }>({
  items,
  onClick,
  }: ListProps<T>) => {
  return (
  <div>
    <h2>List of items</h2>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
     return (
      <div key={item.id} onClick={() => onClick(item)}>
        <div>
          {item.id} {item.fname} {item.lname}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
  </div>
  );
  };

   export default List;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck