# Generic Component in React - Type is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. But no error with JSON.stringify()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-props

I'm trying to create a generic component in React TypeScript. Here is the code

```
interface Props<T> {
    name: T;
}

function CheckChild<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    return <div>My name is {props.name}</div>;
}

export default function Check() {
    const name = "Alex";

    return (
        <div>
            <CheckChild name={name} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

VS code gives me a type error about `props.name`:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
Check2.tsx(7, 21): This type parameter might need an `extends React.ReactPortal` constraint.
Check2.tsx(7, 21): This type parameter might need an `extends React.ReactNode` constraint.
```

But if I wrap `props.name` in JSON.stringify() - type error disappears.

```
return <div>My name is {JSON.stringify(props.name)}</div>;
```

Why does this happen?
[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328515/type-t-is-not-assignable-to-type-reactnode) does not answer my question. I am interested in "Why JSON.stringify removes error"?